# what does scale into mean?

Tags: word-usage

> The analog environments of Industrial era economies
>   were linear. Small efforts provided small returns,
>   large efforts provided large returns, and successful
>   products and strategies often realized a sustained
>   competitive advantage over years or even decades.
>   Driving efficiencies helped add incremental success
>   and **scale into** already successful models, and the
>   bell curve portrayed average, above average, and
>   below average performers. But the world operating
>   by those guidelines is fading away.

What does **scale into** mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wording is kind of abstruse, but I think in this case we're looking at the verb *to scale*, as in meaning #19 on Dictionary.com:

> to adjust in amount according to a fixed scale or proportion (often followed by *down* or *up*):
>   *to scale down wages.*

The idea here being that the business models in question require a certain size of business, so a small business would need to grow in order to *scale [up] into already successful models*.

There is also an implicit reference here to the concept of [economies of scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economies_of_scale).